# Russian characters encoding in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to encode Russian Character correctly in SQL Server. I am using `fnEncodeURL` method of SQL Server.

For example:

```
select dbo.fnEncodeURL('пвы Открытые панели для совместной работы .')
```

which shows me

```
%3F%3F%3F%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%20%3F%3F%3F%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%20.
```

`%3F` means `?` so if we will decode it it would be "??? ???????? ?????? ??? ?????????? ?????? ."

which is incorrect.

So please let me know the correct way so that I could get russian characters in result instead of question marks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use VARCHAR instead of the NVARCHAR? Put up the code of your function

Comment: `select dbo.fnEncodeURL(N'пвы Открытые панели для совместной работы .')` adding N at begining may help you

Comment: `fnEncodeUrl` encodes the text to be safe on the URL - as the name of the function already implies. That is **NOT** what you need to do to **store** such text in your SQL Server database! Just use `NVARCHAR` as your datatype, and if you're inserting text as **string literals** from a script, prepend all your Unicode strings with a `N` characters: `declare @str NVARCHAR(50) = N'.......'`

Comment: Thanks All, 

Allan S. Hansen...i am already using nvarchar for storing it into db and it's working fine ..I need to send these characters via url that's why using fnEncodeURL to encode these characters 

JaydipJ...i have already tried adding N at begining but no luck . 


marc_s....yes you are right that it encodes the text to be safe on URL that's why i am using it...what we are doing we are sending request having russian characters via sql but we are receiving ??? marks instead of correct russian characters...please let me know what should i do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL encoding function uses `VARCHAR` as a datatype and you are passing in an `NVARCHAR` string with non-ASCII characters.

See this for example:

```
select CONVERT(varchar,N'пвы Открытые панели для совместной работы .')
```

returns

```
??? ???????? ?????? ??? ??????
```

You need to replace all your `VARCHAR`s in the procedure to be `NVARCHAR`

If you are talking about [this fnEncodeURL](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=88926) you need to redefine the input parameter and return type like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnEncodeURL
(
    @strInput   varchar(8000)   -- Note: String will get longer, so may overrun 8,000 characters
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
```

should be

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnEncodeURL
(
    @strInput   Nvarchar(8000)  -- Note: String will get longer, so may overrun 8,000 characters
)
RETURNS Nvarchar(8000)
```

You will also need to add all the conversions in the replace logic of that function, I don't know the rules for that.

You could also look into using a SQLCLR and use existing .NET libraries, such as [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/features/) by [@srutzky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577765/srutzky).

Comment: Thanks Tom, this worked for me..but it's showing the same russian character instead of encoded format like %D0%BF%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%0A